# Thermodynamic relations related to S(U,V)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am trying to find that

$$T dS=C_{V}dT+T\left(\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{V} dV$$

I am really close. Here is my walkthrough:

Begin with $S(U,V)$:

$$dS=\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V} dU+\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U}dV$$

Multiplying both sides by $T$ yields

$$TdS=T\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V} dU+T\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U}dV$$

Using the fact that $dU=TdS-PdV$ to see that $$\left(\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V}=T$$

means

$$TdS=dU+T\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U}dV$$

Since $dU=C_{V}dT$,

$$TdS=C_{V} dT+T\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U}dV$$

I'm pretty close now. I just need a Maxwell relation. I know that

$$\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{T}=\left(\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{V}$$

This would get me the final answer, but the issue is that the left-hand term is at constant *temperature*, and I need it to be at constant *internal energy* for it to work. What is the last missing piece?

Answer (score 0):

The equation to work with is dA=-SdT-PdV

Comment: Yes, that gets me the Maxwell relation I showed, but not what I'd need (unless a step prior is wrong).

Comment: Yes.  dU is not equal to Cv dT.  You should start the development with $$dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_TdV=\frac{C_v}{T}dT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_TdV$$

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you! I can get the rest from here.